# How to make website menu item invisible in specific group?

Tags: menu, web, odoo, invisible

I'm working on a private sale website. If the user is a manager, the menu2 will look, else user is a salesman, the menu3 will look.  How can I do that?
What is the best solution?
Here is my code:

```xml
<record id="menu_shop_sales" model="website.menu">
            <field name="name">menu2</field>
            <field name="url">/shop_sales</field>
            <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
            <field name="sequence" type="int">21</field>
        </record>
         <record id="menu_shop_dealer" model="website.menu">
            <field name="name">menu3</field>
            <field name="url">/shop_dealer</field>
            <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
            <field name="sequence" type="int">22</field>
        </record>
```

Comment: You could find a similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786554/manage-webservice-from-odoo/52790554#52790554

Answer (score 0):

Add groups attribute.

```
groups="base.group_user"
```

example:

```
<record id="menu_shop_dealer" model="website.menu">
   <field name="name">menu3</field>
   <field name="url">/shop_dealer</field>
   <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
   <field name="sequence" type="int">22</field>
   <field name="groups">base.group_user</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add groups like this.

```
<field name="groups" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user')])]"/>
```

Or write access rule in csv.